# how to display an image to the left of the text in a titlePanel?

Tags: shiny

I would like to have an image displayed to the left of the titlePanel text.

I have tried:

```
  ...
  titlePanel(
    img(src = "./mylogo.png", height = 60, width = 255),
    "My Title"
  ),
  ...
```

The image gets displayed, however, the text 'My Title' does not get displayed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `titlePanel` function, it looks like the first argument is `title` and the second is a boolean. What you're doing is passing two separate arguments, so the "My Title" is being used as the value for the `windowTitle` parameter. You want both the image and the text to be treated as tags, as one parameter, so try something like

```
 titlePanel(
   tagList(
     img(src = "./mylogo.png", height = 60, width = 255),
     "My Title"
   )
  ),
```

Note: I didn't try running this, and I'm not 100% sure this will work because it's possible that this is only meant to host text because the function documentation says the parameter is `an application title to display`. But if there is a way to achieve what you want, it'll be like this.

This is a very useful technique to know about because there are many shiny contexts in which you're supposed to only give a single tag but you may want to include multiple, so you either have to wrap it in a `<div>` or use a `tagList`